# Issues in publishing an app in the play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm having issues in publishing an app to the Play Store

My app is rejected and the error is:

> Not adhering to user data policy
>
> Not adhering to Google Play Developer Program policy.

Answer (score 0):

When your app gets rejected with "Not adhering to Google Play Developer Program policy."

You must not be following google play policies and once the app is got rejected you will receive mail on the owner's account for the exact issue which your app got rejected